# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver - Not Working

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to run this program

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FirstExample
{
     // JDBC driver name and database URL
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP";

    //  Database credentials
    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "pass";

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try
            {
                //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                //STEP 3: Open a connection
                System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

                //STEP 4: Execute a query
                System.out.println("Creating statement...");
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                String sql;
                sql = "SELECT title,duration,protocol,URL,thumbURL,favorite FROM Videos";
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    //Retrieve by column name
                    String title = rs.getString("title");
                    String duration = rs.getString("duration");
                    String protocol = rs.getString("protocol");
                    String URL = rs.getString("URL");
                    String thumbURL = rs.getString("thumbURL");
                    String favorite = rs.getString("favorite");

                    //Display
                    System.out.println("Title:" + title);
                    System.out.println("Duration:" + duration);
                    System.out.println("Protocol:" + protocol);
                    System.out.println("URL:" + URL);
                    System.out.println("ThumbURL:" + thumbURL);
                    System.out.println("Favorite:" + favorite);
                }

                //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
                conn.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException se)
            {
                //Handle errors for JDBC
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                //Handle errors for Class.forName
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                //finally block used to close resources
                try
                {
                    if(stmt!=null)
                    stmt.close();
                }
                catch(SQLException se2)
                {
                }// nothing we can do
                try
                {
                    if(conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
                }
                catch(SQLException se)
                {
                    se.printStackTrace();
                }//end finally try
            }
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        }
    }
```

But I'm getting the ClassNotFoundException

```
D:\XML Tests>javac FirstExample.java

D:\XML Tests>java FirstExample
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at FirstExample.main(FirstExample.java:21)
Goodbye!
```

Having consulted the numerous question available i.e setting the PATH system variable to the Connector directory, it still isnt working.
Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the jar containing the mysql driver class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` in the classpath.

Comment: I've already done that. Specified C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector J\mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar in Path system variable

Comment: It should be there in the java classpath and not in system path.

Comment: Set the jar in java classpath or run the code using java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar FirstExample

Comment: Doing that it says "Error: Could not find or load main class FirstExample"

Comment: @user2464622 do you compile the code ? U able to c FirstExample.class file ??

Comment: Yes the .class file is created

Comment: can u paste the cmd used to compile the code

Comment: javac FirstExample.java

Comment: so sorry i mean to say cmd to run it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47655/discussion-between-niks-tyagi-and-user2464622)

Answer (score 0):

Add `MySQL` driver jar to your project classpath and done.

Answer (score 0):

The error is trying to tell you that it's not able to find the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` which is required when you are using MySql for data storage. So What you need to do is download the [JConnector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html). And then import that jar file into your project classpath. Then you will not get the error.

Comment: I'm already using that..is it a problem of it not detecting the driver?

Comment: Have you included it in the classpath of project ?